# Obtener CSV en ZIP de un sitio con Basic Auth mediante Google Apps Script (google sheets)

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script, zip, google-spreadsheets

Estoy tratando de obtener un csv que está zipeado en una url, la cual necesita basic auth. No puedo lograrlo, ya que me tira un error de sintaxis en el argumento de la variable 'files'. Esto es lo que intenté:

```js
function importdatastreamcsv() {

  var user = 'user';
  var pw = 'pass';

  var csvUrl = 'https://example.com/api/datastream/download/58350?tableIds=67595&usePreferences=false';
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl,{headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + pw, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)}});
  var files = Utilities.unzip(csvContent)[0]; //error de sintaxis en el argumento! :(
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(files.getDataAsString());


  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  sheet.setValues(csvData);


}
```

Para asegurarme probé con otros archivos ejemplo en la web y pude hacerlo correctamente, como muestro aquí:

```js
function importdatastreamcsv() {

  var user = 'x';
  var pw = 'x';
  var csvUrl = 'http://spatialkeydocs.s3.amazonaws.com/FL_insurance_sample.csv.zip'  
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl)//,{headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + pw, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)}});
  Logger.log(typeof(csvContent));
  var files = Utilities.unzip(csvContent)[0];
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(files.getDataAsString());
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

   
}
```

Buscando otras alternativas, me di cuenta de que podía traer la misma data en formato html (sin zip-csv). Escribí otro script para esto, el cual funciona parcialmente, ya que recibo toda la data en una sola celda y en formato html plano. Pero debería ser en varias celdas formato tabla...acá va el código:

```js
function importdatastreamhtml() {

  var user = 'user';
  var pw = 'pass';
  var csvUrl = 'https://example.com/api/datastream/download/58350?tableIds=67595&usePreferences=false&format=web'; 
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl,{headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + pw, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)}});
  var html = csvContent.getContentText();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1);
  sheet.setValue(html);


}
```

Necesito que por lo menos uno de los dos códigos me funcione, mejor si es e primero. Qué me puede estar faltando? El resultado final debería ser una simple tabla.

Comment: Argumento no válido (línea 36, archivo "Código")

La línea 36 es la de 'var files'

Comment: Lo más probable es que el valor de csvContent no sea un objeto de tipo Blob. ¿Cuál es el tipo de objeto de csvContent?

Comment: Lo más probable es que te haga falta el comando getBlob()

Comment: Gracias por tu atención Rubén. Soy nuevo en esto, cómo se qué tipo de objeto es? probé con typeof y me da 'object'.
Intenté añadir .getBlob() luego de csvContent pero me tira el mismo error.
Con getContent() me dice esto: No se puede convertir Array en BlobSource.
Y con getContentText: No se puede encontrar el método unzip(string).

Ya no se qué otra cosa probar para que funcione. Espero puedas ayudarme.

Comment: Lamentablemente el código que has incluido incluye una dirección ficticia así que el intento de reproducir el problema implica más tiempo del que sería necesario en caso de que el que se incluyera un URL real, aunque fuera a un archivo creado explícitamente para fines de demostración.

Comment: Entiendo, pero por temas de seguridad de la empresa donde trabajo no tengo permitido revelar estos datos. Sino hubiese puesto la dirección real desde un principio. Sin embargo doy fe de que el archivo zip que contiene el csv se descarga correctamente cuando ingreso la url en el navegador y escribo manualmente mi usuario y contraseña en el prompt, y que este csv tiene data correcta en utf-8.

Comment: No pongas una dirección de un archivo del trabajo, pon la de otro archivo, uno que hayas creado para fines de demostración o de un archivo público que sirva para los mismos fines. De hecho, dado que el problema no tiene que ver con la autenticación básica puedes dejar de lado esa parte. El asunto es crear un [mcve].

Comment: Subí mi archivo original a otra direccion web, cambie la url del script a esta nueva direccion, y funcionó perfectamente. De hecho el script sirve para cuaquier archivo csv dentro de zip. Modifico la pregunta original con un ejemplo de esto. Debido a que el problema tampoco está en la autorización (el script de html se autoriza bien), donde estará el problema?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68939/discussion-between-ruben-and-cesar-requena).